# Incorrect operation on a sql server procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with an online game.

In the virtual machine with Windows Server 2012R2 + SQL Server 2017 CU31, the procedure works without errors.

But on my machine with Windows Server 2022 + SQL Server 2019 CU18, it doesn't work.

This is the log error:

> [Error] ERR(GET): SQL_ERROR >> { CALL SelectBase_proc10 ( 1, 4 ) }
> [Error] SqlState:HY000, NativeError:4096  Msg:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Protocol error in TDS stream
> [System] [_QueryCase_SelectChar::vComplete] (1)(2) Load Failed. Result(20)

Where is the error?

I haven't tried to fix it yet because I'm new to database

Comment: Missing some details here -- what language/framework is your client software written in, what version of the ODBC driver is being used, and what does the connection string look like in each case? Also, your stored procedure definition is incomplete in that it's missing the parameter declaration.

Comment: the client and server are compiled, but the game was made in c# using cry engine 3, and a private server, version of ODBC and 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out what and not and error in the procedure, this error appears when I install the sql server on the ssd. When installing on hd the error disappeared.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).